# rxSwift Observable dependency

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I’m new to rxSwift. I have 3 observables, the checkAccount, fetchMails and fetchFolders.
fetchMails and fetchFolders depend on the checkAccount result. How can I invoke the fetchMails and fetchFolders operation using the UIButton Tap? And if the checkAccount success, I don't what it to run each time I fetchMails and fetchFolders. If checkAccount Failed, I want to retry checkAccount when fetchMails and fetchFolders. How can I To achieve this purpose? and This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!
var checkAccountO: Observable<Bool>?
let bag = DisposeBag()

let fetchO: Observable<[String]> = Observable.create { observer in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1000)) {
            observer.onNext(["1","2"])
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }

let fetchFolderO: Observable<[String]>  =  Observable.create { observer in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1000)) {
            observer.onNext(["folder1","folder2"])
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchFolders().subscribe { (evetn) in
        print("folders \(evetn)")
    }.addDisposableTo(bag)

    fetchMails().subscribe { (evetn) in
        print("mails \(evetn)")
    }.addDisposableTo(bag)
}

func checkAccount() -> Observable<Bool> {
    if let ob = checkAccountO {
        return ob
    }
    checkAccountO = Observable.create { (observer) -> Disposable in
        print("checking...")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1000)) {
            let i = arc4random() % 2
            if i == 0 {
                print("succ")
                observer.onNext(true)
                observer.onCompleted()
            }else {
                print("failed:\(i)")
                let err = NSError.init(domain: "err", code: 1001, userInfo: nil)
                observer.onError(err)
            }
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }.retry(3).shareReplay(1)
    return checkAccountO!
}

func fetchMails() -> Observable<[String]> {
    return checkAccount().flatMap({ (_) -> Observable<[String]> in
        return self.fetchO
    })
}

func fetchFolders() -> Observable<[String]> {
    return checkAccount().flatMap({ (_) -> Observable<[String]> in
        return self.fetchFolderO
    })
}
```

according to @Timofey Solonin's answer, I change the fetchFoders and fetchMails observable to flatmap from button.rx.tap like this, but still not known how to use retrywhen

```
    func fetchMails() -> Observable<[String]> {
    let rxtap = btn1.rx.tap
    return rxtap.flatMap { (_) -> Observable<[String]> in
        return self.checkAccount().flatMap({ (_) -> Observable<[String]> in
            return self.fetchO
        })
    }

}

func fetchFolders() -> Observable<[String]> {
    let rxtap = btn2.rx.tap
    return rxtap.flatMap { (_) -> Observable<[String]> in
        return self.checkAccount().flatMap({ (_) -> Observable<[String]> in
            return self.fetchFolderO
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `retryWhen` operator. `flatMap` the error stream from `retryWhen` to `checkAccount` and if `checkAccount` will be successful your operation will retry.

To start a stream from button you use `button.rx.tap` and `flatMap` it.

For example if you want to `fetchMail()` from `button.rx.tap` and `checkAcount()` multiple times if `fetchMail()` errored out you can use:

```
btn1.rx.tap.flatMapLatest {
    fetchMails().retryWhen{ errors in 
        errors.flatMapLatest{ _ in 
            checkAccount().retry() //or you can use retry(n) if you want to retry checkAccount limited amount of times.
            //fetchMails() will repeat if checkAccount() will return anything. Just keep in mind that retryWhen block is not going to be called if checkAccount() was successful.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much.  I have figure out how to using button.rx.tap to invoke the fetchMails and  fetchfolders observable now. But I just don't know how to use retrywhen to make checkAccount to achieve my purpose: when checkAccount success, it only run once. if checkaccount failed, then every time fetchmails will try to checkaccount first until it success. can you show me some code?

Comment: @bupo.jung take a look at the example in my updated answer. Does it solve your issue?

Comment: No, It's not what I want. I mean fetchmails is depend on the checkaccount result. if first tap on button checkaccount success,  then run fetchmails and get the results, then other taps after will run fetchmails only ; if first tap on button checkaccount failed, I will not run fetchmails but show the error,  then tap button again will still checkaccount first and so on.